# NRWL NX - Why do I get "Cannot find name 'describe'" when running "ng serve express"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nrwl-nx

I created a plain `@nrwl/express` project with an empty web server `server.ts`:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({status: 'OK'})
});

var server = app.listen(3000);

module.exports = { server }
```

Whenever I add one a test file such as `something.test.ts`:

```js
const { server } = require('../server');

describe('TEST: /', () => {
  it('Should work just fine', async () => {
    // all ok
  });
});

export {};
```

Then `ng serve express` starts complaining because it tries to process the test files:

```
TS2593: Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? 
Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha` and then add `jest` or `mocha` to the types
field in your tsconfig.
```

What is the correct way to solve this? I don't necessarily want to add test libraries as a runtime dependency because test files shouldn't be bundled in the build IMO.

Comment: They won't be bundled in the build. Did you try what it said and install the types? Those are just the d.ts files that let typescript know what they are.

Comment: I tried to do an `npm i @types/jest` as suggested above but and verified that 'jest' was already present in the `types` field in `tsconfig`. I think that there should be a better way to do this considering that Jest comes automatically within Nrwl NX. I don't want to believe that they would have forgotten to add this important dependency.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out after a couple of days (face-palm)

I needed to edit `tsconfig.app.json` and needed to add `"**/*.test.ts"` in the exclude option:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../dist/out-tsc",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Everything is working fine now, warning messages are gone.

Comment: I had similar issue, but with a Nest.js library. I had `compilerOptions.types` set to `[]`; I was missing `node` types, thus setting its value to `["node"]` fixed my problem.